# How to set a UITableView frame so it fills a popover

Tags: ios, uitableview, uipopovercontroller

I want to fill a popover with a UITableView.  The height of the popover varies depending upon the orientation of the device etc.  How can I set the UITableView properties so it always fills the available size of the popover, and vertically scrolls when necessary?

Comment: Well... `tableView.frame = popover.bounds;` is not sufficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@H2CO3 is correct.

In your action when you present the popover, do something like:

```
mytableView.frame = myPopover.bounds;
```

That way, your table view will match the popover it is in.

Then when you want it to scroll do this:

```
[self.tableView setScrollEnabled:YES];
```